# Wifi toggle script not running properly through i3

Tags: shell-script, networking, networkmanager, window-manager, i3

I have the following line in my `~/.i3/config`:

```
bindsym XF86WLAN exec ~/.i3/i3-scripts/toggle-wifi.sh
```

`toggle-wifi.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if nmcli nm wifi | grep -q "disabled" ; then
    nmcli nm wifi on
    notify-send -i network-wireless-full "Wireless enabled" "Your wireless adaptor has been enabled."
else
    nmcli nm wifi off
    notify-send -i network-wireless-disconnected "Wireless disabled" "Your wireless adaptor has been disabled."
fi
```

The script works fine when running from terminal with `./toggle-wifi.sh` but when I run it using the keyboard binding with i3, it only ever *enables* wifi, never *disables*.

A strange thing is, if I press the key to run the script many times quickly, it says `Wireless disabled` once. Otherwise it always says `Wireless enabled`.

Can anyone help or offer any alternative scripts to do the same thing?

Comment: Maybe is the key also parsed by another app, and you end with a race condition? I'd try binding to another, unrelated key. (You could have edited your question instead of removing it and asking a new one.)

Comment: @L.Levrel Thanks. The key seems to be the issue. Is there an easy way to find where else this key is used?

Comment: Isn't your WM already binding the key? You could look for XF86WLAN in your conf files (or the default conf files).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. If you'd like to create an answer for the question, I can approve it.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Another thought: do you have nm-applet running? It would be a likely candidate for the mysterious XF86WLAN parser.

Comment: Yes I did, but closing it didn't help.

Comment: After killing nm-applet then hitting the key, is nm-applet back?

Comment: No it isn't back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a race condition: another app may be parsing the same key to toggle Wifi.

This can be checked by binding your script to an unrelated key: if this other key makes your script work as expected, then you have a race condition on XF86WLAN.